# iOS How to know original video creation date of video?

Tags: ios, video

I am currently creating an app that charges fines through illegal driveway videos.

An illegal driving car video taken by a complainant must submit the original video, but it will be a problem if you submit the converted video instead of the original video.

To determine if it is the original video or not, I want to know the original video creation date of the video converted by someone?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the `creationDate` property of `PHAsset`:

```
let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([videoUrl], options: nil).firstObject as! PHAsset
print("Creation Date: " + String(asset.creationDate))
```

Comment: creation date be immutable ?

Comment: No, you can change the creation date.